# Process Builder - No Errors, but not working

Tags: salesforce, processbuilder

Have a process builder that works when I manually update a field, but not when our B2BMA (Pardot User) "updates" the field. A few Details:

Default Campaign Member Status: Sent
PB Type: Record Update
Object: CampaignMember = Is Created or Updated
Criteria:

1. CampaignMember.Status isChanged = True
2. CampaignMember.Status Equals, Picklist Value = A

These decisions call an apex class and post a message in slack. When I manually changed the "Campaign Member Status" field, the process triggers and works perfectly. But, when the status is updated by B2BMA (pardot user) the process is not triggered. No errors are being presented.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but could it be that the Pardot User does not have rights to execute the apex class, or maybe read rights on the fields?

(look at the debug log for that user)